# If select option text length is greater than 10 then trim jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a select/drop-down on my site, the width is 150 pixels and some of the option values are really long, my issue is that if I select a long option it it cuts off in my select.

I want to somehow say, on change, trim the value that is displayed so its only 10 characters and append '...'

Is this possible?

You can see what I've been trying here...

http://jsfiddle.net/yjeAN/1/

With...

```
$('select').change(function(){
    if($(this).val().length() >= 10){ 
        alert('long title');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    if(this.value.length >= 10){ 
        console.log('long title');

        //trimming
        var trim = $.trim(this.value).substring(0, 10) + "...";
        alert(trim);

        //Set the text in the select
        $(this).find("option:selected").text(trim);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yjeAN/3/

Comment: You forgot to set the trimmed val to select box.

Comment: all good until you want to select another one, the the previously selected one will still be trimmed